# Run the same web application on ASP.NET 2 and 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0, asp.net-4.0

Can you run the same web application (ASP.NET MVC 2) on ASP.NET 2 as well as ASP.NET 4? The application is developed and built for .NET 3.5 SP1.

My initial guess is you can't, due to vast differences in standard web.config files between these two runtimes. Is this correct?

If two web.configs were supplied, one for each ASP.NET version, should it, in principle at least, run correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A .NET 2 app should still run under Framework 4.x, but not *necessarily* the other way round - that would depend if you've used any framework features that weren't present in the earlier version.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, but I'm specifically interested in ASP.NET.

Comment: ASP.NET *is* what I'm talking about when I refer to the 'Framework'.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. So, you agree that web.config changes are needed or are you claiming that it will work with same web.config?

Comment: You'll likely need a slight variation in the web.config - but not necessarily - especially if your webapp isn't very complex. For example, the version for 4.0 may need `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` added. Have a look at [this](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes) for more potential errors and fixes.